# Laravel 8: NPM error / webpack.mix.js doesn't compile to public folder

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-8

Please help me i dont know why I got this error.
this is the only thing I do.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel_vue_sample
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue
npm install && npm run dev
```

I don't know why I cant see a folder in public.

[image]

Comment: $ npm -v
6.14.11

$ node -v
v14.16.0

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same, and right above the error you mentioned it suggests to install a legacy dependancy:

`npm install vue-loader@^15.9.7 --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps`

after installing that it works just fine